# How to expand the .lib with its source in c++?

Tags: c++, windows, disassembly

Now my problem requires a `.lib` and I've grabbed all the source for that library,how can I replace the `.lib` dependance with its source code so that I can trace directly in source level instead of disassembly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you compile the source files for the `.lib` file with debugging information included, then you can continue to link the `.lib` file into your executable and the debugger will know how to find the source files.

You may be using a `.lib` file at the moment that's compiled without debugging information, so the debugger will not support source-level debugging of that code.